# Get-ChildItem in an enormous directory and RAM usage

Tags: powershell, ram, get-childitem

I have created a PS script on a domain controller (SRV2012R2).

The script checks every shared folder (mapped drive) to see if there are any files present larger than 2GB:

```
foreach($dir in $Dirs)
{
    $files = Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse 

    foreach ($item in $files)
    {

       #Check if $item.Size is greater than 2GB

    }
}
```

I have the following problem:

The shares are pretty filled with over 800GB of (sub)folders, files and most of them are just normal documents.

Whenever I run my script, I see that the CPU+RAM consumes enormous amounts while running my script (after 5 minutes into the `Get-Childitem`-line, the RAM has already reached >4GB).

My question is, why does `Get-ChildItem` need so many resources? What alternative can I use? Because I haven't manage to run my script succesfully.

I have seen that I can use `| SELECT fullname, length` after my `Get-ChildItem`-clause as an improvement, but this hasn't helped me at all (query still consumes enormous RAM).

Is there anything I can do in order that I can loop through the directories without much resistance from the machine resources?

Comment: What is your end-goal?  You can just as easily accomplish this in one line: `$Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $PSItem.Length -gt 2GB }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving every single file to a variable, use the pipeline to filter out the ones you don't need (ie. those smaller than 2GB):

```
foreach($dir in $Dirs)
{
    $bigFiles = Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse |Where Length -gt 2GB
}
```

If you need to process or analyze these big files further, I'd suggest you extend that pipeline with `ForEach-Object`:

```
foreach($dir in $Dirs)
{
    Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse |Where Length -gt 2GB |ForEach-Object {
      # do whatever else you must
      # $_ contains the current file
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how could I loop through $bigFiles after? How could I check the amount of `$bigFiles`?

Comment: @user3127554 `$bigFiles.Count`

Comment: Either use your current approach, or tag `ForEach-Object` at the end of the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Create an Array
$BigFilesArray = @()

#Populate it with your data
$BigFilesArray = @(ForEach-Object($dir in $dirs) {Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse | Where-Object Length -GT 2GB})

#Number of items in the array
$BigFilesArray.Count

#Looping to get the name and size of each item in the array
ForEach-Object ($bf in $BigFilesArray) {"$($bf.name) - $($bf.length)"}
```

Hope this helps!